# bash: syntax error near unexpected token

Tags: bash, alias, function

I'm trying to create a bash alias `alias backlight='__backlight () { echo "$@"; cd ~/Code/MSI-Backlight; sudo nodejs ~/Code/MSI-Backlight/msi-backlight.js "$@"; }'`, it works fine with no parameters but breaks when I give it one. It works fine outside of an alias. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define it as a function and call it with the alias:

```
function __blacklight() {
  echo "$@";
  cd ~/Code/MSI-Backlight;
  sudo nodejs ~/Code/MSI-Backlight/msi-backlight.js "$@";
}
alias backlight='__blacklight'
```

Comment: or just define `backlight` as a function and forget about the alias.

Comment: It works, is there also a way I could make it not actually change direcotires, like using parenthesies in aliases?

Comment: Ah, I used `pushd [dir]` and the `popd` when I was done.